# Loop is not incrementing

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript.

I have to create a function that returns the next multiples of 5 based on a given number.But my loop repeats the information, it doesn´t increment the result.What am I doing wrong?

```
function proS(num, mult) {
  let arr = []

  for (var i = 1; i <= mult; i++) {
    arr.push(Math.ceil(num / 5) * 5)
  }
  return arr
}

proS(6, 4)
```

returns `[10, 10, 10, 10]`

Comment: In `arr.push(Math.ceil(num / 5) * 5)` you use `num` which never changes.

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: @Barmar I think the OP is asking given `num`, what are the next 5 multiples of `num`. (I.E, if `num` = 5, then the OP wants `proS()` to return `[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `(n / 5) * 5` will always be `n`

Answer (score 4):

you should use your formula to produce the initial value of `num`, then add `5` to it each time through the loop.

```js
function proS(num, mult) {
  let arr = []
  num = Math.ceil(num / 5) * 5;
  for (var i = 1; i <= mult; i++, num += 5) {
    arr.push(num)
  }
  return arr
}

console.log(proS(6, 4))
```

Comment: Isn't the OP asking for the next 5 multiples of `num`?

Comment: No, it says "next multiples of 5"

Comment: This is the correct answer based on what was asked, but I will also add that you could replace the `arr.push()` line in OP's original code with `arr.push(Math.floor(Math.ceil((5 * i) + num) / 5) * 5);` to get the same results as seen here.

Comment: Yes, there are several ways to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I won't write the answer, but I'll point you in the right direction. If you pay close attention `arr.push(Math.ceil(num / 5) * 5)` this bit of code is invariant. This means that you should probably add the variable `i` somewhere in there so that it actually returns a different output every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

thanks guys, I ended up doing this and it worked:

```
function proS (num, mult){
let arr = []
let res = (Math.ceil(num / 5) * 5)

for (var i = 1; i <= mult; i ++){
arr.push(res)
res += 5
}
return arr
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are pushing the same value to the array without changing it at any point.

```
Math.ceil(num / 5) * 5
```

does not change because num does not change

```
for (var i = 0; i < mult; i ++){
   arr.push((Math.ceil(num / 5)+i) * 5)
}
```

will increment each result by 5 according to i

Answer (score -1):

The loop is returning and pushing to the array the same value every round because the expression you have inside the loop is invariant for i changes. With the expression `Math.ceil(num / 5) * 5` you're getting the next multiple of 5 of the num parameter. You have to increase this number by 5 every on every loop iteration. For example, try this:

```
function proS (num, mult){
    let arr = []
    const nextMultipleOf5 = Math.ceil(num / 5) * 5
    for (var i = 0; i <= mult - 1; i ++){
        arr.push(nextMultipleOf5 + 5*i)
    }

    return arr
}
```